# Implement a switch statement using a jump table in C++

Tags: c++, performance, switch-statement, memory-address

I am trying to improve my parser's speed. And `switch-case`, sometimes it's useful, but I see it's still slow. Not sure - if C++ supports this feature (address checkpoints (**with additional parameter**)), it's great!

Simple example :

```
enum Transport //MOTORBIKE = 1, CAR = 2,  ...  SHIP = 10
Transport foo = //unknown

    switch(foo)
{
    case MOTORBIKE : /*do something*/ break;
    case CAR : /*do something*/ break;
    //////////////////////////
    case SHIP : /*do something*/ break;
}
```

If the variable **`foo`** is **`SHIP`**, at least the program has to re-check the value up to ten times! -> It's still slow.

**If C++ supports checkpoints** :

```
Transport foo = //unknown
__checkpoint smart_switch;

goto (smart_switch + foo); //instant call!!!

smart_switch + MOTORBIKE : /*do something*/ goto __end;
smart_switch + CAR : /*do something*/ goto __end;
smart_switch + [...] : /*do something*/ goto __end;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
smart_switch + SHIP : /*do something*/ goto __end;

__end : return 0;
```

It doesn't generate any jump tables, and then check per value. Maybe it doesn't work well with `default` case. The only thing is **`smart_switch + CAR`** -> **`smart_switch + SHIP`** may have different addresses so if C++ evaluate them as real addresses, the process will fail. So when compiling the compiler just has to convert them to real addresses.

Does C++ support this feature? And does it greatly improve speed & performance?

Comment: I highly doubt that it's the `switch` that is slowing you. But you can of course try and replace it with an array or `map` or `unordered_map` that translates values to function pointers.

Comment: @Jon that's definitely will be slower than switch. It is very hard to beat the speed of switch that compiler generates.

Comment: @Slava: The compiler writes code, same as you. It doesn't have magic pixie dust.

Comment: Actually the `switch()` statement is the equivalent of magic pixie dust, compared to fully-dynamic containers like `map` or `unordered_map`.  The compiler can make quite a few assumptions about input data, can inline function calls, and can fold redundant portions of code across various entries of the switch.  None of that happens if its using a container of function pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are talking about is called a jump table. The jump table is usually an array of relative addresses where the program execution control can be transferred. Here is an example of how you can implement one:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    static constexpr void* jump_table[] =
    {
        &&print_0, &&print_1, &&print_2,
        &&print_3, &&print_4, &&print_5
    };

    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    int v = std::rand();

    if (v < 0 || v > 5)
        goto out;

    goto *jump_table[v];

print_0:
    std::printf("zero\n");
    goto out;
print_1:
    std::printf("one\n");
    goto out;
print_2:
    std::printf("two\n");
    goto out;
print_3:
    std::printf("three\n");
    goto out;
print_4:
    std::printf("four\n");
    goto out;
print_5:
    std::printf("five\n");
    goto out;
out:
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I seriously doubt two things. The first doubt is that using jump table will make your program faster. An indirect jump is relatively expensive and is badly predicted by the hardware. Chances are that if you only have three values then you are better off simply comparing each of them using "if-then-else" statement. For a lot of sparse values (i.e. 1, 100, 250, 500 etc.), you are better off doing a binary search rather than blowing up the size of your table.  In either case, this is just a head of a huge iceberg when it comes to switch statements. So unless you know all of the details and know where compiler did the wrong thing for your particular case, don't even bother trying to change switch to something else — you will never outsmart the compiler and will only make your program slower.

The second doubt is actually that switching is the bottleneck of your parser. Most likely it is not. So in order to save yourself a lot of valuable time, try profiling your code first to know for sure what is the slowest part of your program. Usually it goes in steps like this:

1. Profile and find the bottleneck.
2. Figure out why this is a bottleneck and come up with a reasonable idea of how to improve the code for speed.
3. Try to improve the code.
4. Go to step #1.

And there is no exit from this loop. Optimization is something you can spend your entire life doing. At some point, you will have to assume the program is fast enough and there are no bottlenecks :)

Also, I have written a more comprehensive analysis with in-depth (more or less) details on how switch statements are implemented by compilers and when and when not try to engage in trying to outsmart them. Please find the article [here](http://lazarenko.me/switch/).

Comment: I guess `v = rand()` must be a `v = rand() % 6;` Otherwise program prints nothing.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... What is the `&&` in `&&print_0`? I expected to see a single `&`, not a double one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes C/C++ does support this feature, and it is in... standard switch. I have no idea where you get the idea that switch will check each value, but you are wrong. Yes I heard that some compilers can generate better code for pretty big cases (many variants like probably several hundreds), but I do not think that it is yours.
For example following code compiled by gcc without any optimization:

```
enum E { One, Two, Three, Four, Five };

void func( E e )
{
    int res;
    switch( e ) {
        case One : res = 10; break;
        case Two : res = 20; break;
        case Three : res = 30; break;
        case Four : res = 40; break;
        case Five : res = 50; break;
    }
}
```

generates following:

```
_Z4func1E:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl    $4, %eax
    ja  .L1
    movl    %eax, %eax
    movq    .L8(,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp *%rax
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
    .align 4
.L8:
    .quad   .L3
    .quad   .L4
    .quad   .L5
    .quad   .L6
    .quad   .L7
    .text
.L3:
    movl    $10, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L1
.L4:
    movl    $20, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L1
.L5:
    movl    $30, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L1
.L6:
    movl    $40, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L1
.L7:
    movl    $50, -4(%rbp)
    nop
.L1:
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
```

As you can see it simply jumps into particular position without checking each value.

Comment: -1: Where did *you* get the idea that switch will *not* check each value? Certainly not from the standard.

Comment: Before putting your downvote please check how it actually works. I got that idea from looking into assembly code for example

Comment: So, you looked at the assembly produced by *some particular compiler* using *some particular settings* when compiling *some particular code* and that's "how it works"?

Comment: No I know how switch works, and know how it is usually implemented instead of somebody that suggests using map instead.

Comment: I hope you understand the difference between *usually* and *how it works*, and also take into account that *you have not seen the actual code* and *you do not know which compiler is used*. Nothing more to add.

Comment: There is enough information in question. If you do not understand something it is better to learn, instead of leaving nonsense comments.

Comment: Actually, +1. What you have shown is a darn simple jump table. This is exactly [how switches are implemented](http://lazarenko.me/2013/01/13/switch-statement-machine-code/) for a range of five continuous values.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: The problem is that Slava *overgeneralizes* and advertises "standard" behavior as "ISO C++ standard" behavior ("C/C++ supports this" -- actually no, the *compiler* does). In addition, the answer does not offer *anything* to the OP (in contrast to yours, which I have upvoted). And finally, it doesn't help that he goes even further in his assumptions regarding what I know or understand, declaring the comments nonsense etc etc.

Comment: @Jon: Oh well, you are so strict and demanding. I agree with you on this one. One thing I know for sure is that it is extremely hard to teach people and learning to write good answers takes time. Generally I prefer not to downvote anything unless it is extremely incorrect to the point when it can harmful the reading learner`s mind. I guess I don't find this answer as one of them. And thanks for upvoting me, it is always a pleasure to receive a feedback and a great pleasure to get a positive one.

Comment: I advertise standard behavior as "ISO C++ standard"? Please read original question: "Not sure - if C++ supports this feature". Do you really think author of the question asked "does ISO C++ standard supports this feature?". If I staying on author level and try to explain in his level, there is no reason to become terminology nazi. Especially when you, Jon, actually did not provide any usable answer, your suggestion for map over switch cannot be counted as one.

Comment: +1 If you need a switch, you should write a switch. If your compiler implements the switch in a manner that performs poorly when it could easily implement it in a manner that performs well, you should consider a different compiler. The standard gives compilers the latitude to do this right, and they should be expected to do so.

Comment: There's no such language as C/C++.

Answer (score -1):

You can just build an array with function pointers and index at it by the enum

Comment: Calling a function is slow, especially functions which have less code. I have to check values many times. EDIT : And, I have to handle lots of my local variables...

Comment: @xersi Have you actually profiled any of this? Yes, calling functions has some overhead, but your function has to do next to nothing for this to really matter.

Comment: @us2012 you should try to profile before comment like this. Yes functon is slow comparing to switch. If you care of the speed of code that compiler generates, then calling function does matter, and inline function there for purpose

Comment: @Slava Depends on many things, like the speed of your comparison operator for your objects (if that one is slow, a lookup of the function pointer in a map will be a lot cheaper than trying an average of `O(n)` `switch` cases).  Of course function calls can have an overhead, but all I'm saying is: Don't assume that they're the problem until you profiled the code you are working on to prove it.

Comment: Comparison operator for objects? Do you really understand how switch works in C/C++?